# JVM server.port Options

Tags: maven, jvm, spring-boot

What does the jvm option `-Dserver.port=-1` mean? I know setting it to 0 means random port. There is a nice article [here](http://spring.io/blog/2014/03/07/deploying-spring-boot-applications).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means "create a WebApplicationContext, but don't start the server".

Comment: Thanks Dave!

Can you comment on how this option could effect if we are using an embedded server such as any spring-boot application?

Comment: That's what I meant (it's the embedded server that isn't started).

Answer (score 0):

Lets take a look at two screenshots taken from a same test spring application running with different options.

```
C:\>java -jar -Dserver.contextPath=/testapp -Dserver.port=0 spring-security-test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.0.2.RELEASE)

2014-05-29 10:22:36.434  INFO 10172 --- [           main] s.t.spring.security.config.Application   : Starting Application on KOLTM28902K0NX with PID 10172 (C:\spring-security-test-
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar started by 607130889 in C:\)
2014-05-29 10:22:36.481  INFO 10172 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWe
bApplicationContext@1d256fa: startup date [Thu May 29 10:22:36 IST 2014]; root of context hierarchy
2014-05-29 10:22:37.619  INFO 10172 --- [           main] .t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory : Server initialized with port: 0
2014-05-29 10:22:37.744  INFO 10172 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2014-05-29 10:22:37.744  INFO 10172 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.52
2014-05-29 10:22:37.853  INFO 10172 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[localhost].[/testapp]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2014-05-29 10:22:37.853  INFO 10172 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1372 ms
2014-05-29 10:22:38.805  INFO 10172 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AnyRequest
Matcher@1, [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@a30fd, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter
@cad437, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@1f18cbe, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@725967, org.springframework.security.web.authenticatio
n.logout.LogoutFilter@1ed688f, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@10ff62a, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCa
cheAwareFilter@f18d37, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@1c0b8a0, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthent
icationFilter@11650d6, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@178c490, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@1de7497, org.spr
ingframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@4d28c7]
2014-05-29 10:22:38.867  INFO 10172 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.e.ServletRegistrationBean        : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2014-05-29 10:22:38.867  INFO 10172 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'springSecurityFilterChain' to: [/*]
2014-05-29 10:22:38.867  INFO 10172 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2014-05-29 10:22:39.148  INFO 10172 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframewo
rk.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2014-05-29 10:22:39.211  INFO 10172 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/hello] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.se
rvlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController]
2014-05-29 10:22:39.211  INFO 10172 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/home] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.ser
vlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController]
2014-05-29 10:22:39.211  INFO 10172 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/login] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.se
rvlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController]
2014-05-29 10:22:39.211  INFO 10172 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Root mapping to handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.Para
meterizableViewController]
2014-05-29 10:22:39.273  INFO 10172 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servl
et.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2014-05-29 10:22:39.273  INFO 10172 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.w
eb.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2014-05-29 10:22:39.585  INFO 10172 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2014-05-29 10:22:39.663  INFO 10172 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 56822/http
2014-05-29 10:22:39.663  INFO 10172 --- [           main] s.t.spring.security.config.Application   : Started Application in 3.666 seconds (JVM running for 4.056)
```

We can see the server started with a random port available when the application was run with `-Dserver.port=0`.

```
 .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.0.2.RELEASE)

2014-05-29 09:59:31.815  INFO 2756 --- [           main] s.t.spring.security.config.Application   : Starting Application on KOLTM28902K0NX with PID 2756 (C:\Users\607130889\Share\s
pring-security-test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar started by 607130889 in C:\Users\607130889\Share)
2014-05-29 09:59:31.908  INFO 2756 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWeb
ApplicationContext@1c5f743: startup date [Thu May 29 09:59:31 IST 2014]; root of context hierarchy
2014-05-29 09:59:34.295  INFO 2756 --- [           main] .t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory : Server initialized with port: -1
2014-05-29 09:59:34.748  INFO 2756 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2014-05-29 09:59:34.748  INFO 2756 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.52
2014-05-29 09:59:35.013  INFO 2756 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[localhost].[/secure]        : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2014-05-29 09:59:35.013  INFO 2756 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3105 ms
2014-05-29 09:59:36.526  INFO 2756 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AnyRequestM
atcher@1, [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@167c6fd, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilte
r@139d115, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@19d9c0d, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@1384ed5, org.springframework.security.web.authentica
tion.logout.LogoutFilter@14189d0, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@2cd728, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.Request
CacheAwareFilter@83de21, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@1b2380e, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthe
nticationFilter@39452f, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@154c054, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@5db9eb, 
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@1353154]
2014-05-29 09:59:36.589  INFO 2756 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.e.ServletRegistrationBean        : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2014-05-29 09:59:36.604  INFO 2756 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'springSecurityFilterChain' to: [/*]
2014-05-29 09:59:36.604  INFO 2756 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2014-05-29 09:59:37.213  INFO 2756 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframewor
k.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2014-05-29 09:59:37.415  INFO 2756 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/hello] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.ser
vlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController]
2014-05-29 09:59:37.415  INFO 2756 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/home] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.serv
let.mvc.ParameterizableViewController]
2014-05-29 09:59:37.415  INFO 2756 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/login] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.ser
vlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController]
2014-05-29 09:59:37.415  INFO 2756 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Root mapping to handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.Param
eterizableViewController]
2014-05-29 09:59:37.431  INFO 2756 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servle
t.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2014-05-29 09:59:37.431  INFO 2756 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2014-05-29 09:59:37.805  INFO 2756 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2014-05-29 09:59:37.868  INFO 2756 --- [           main] s.t.spring.security.config.Application   : Started Application in 7.551 seconds (JVM running for 9.08)
```

Here the server start notification is missing when the application was run with `server.port=-1` opntion.